# HTML5 Web Audio API: Filters is not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I looking now at this [**article**](http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-api-filters) and it interested me, but unfortunately the [**real examples**](http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio-filters/) of HTML5 Web Audio Filters are not working. Can anyone please help me to sort it out, what is the problem, because I want to evaluate and work with this example.
 Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just look in the console and you'll see the errors.  Around line 595 of index.html, it's failing because the article is using the old deprecated types for biquadfilter - numeric values - and it needs to be changed to use the new string-based values.  (I.e. a value of "3" - the default lowshelf filter - needs to be passed into currentFilterType as "lowshelf".)  See http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-biquadfilternode-interface.

Comment: Can I ask you for a help, to help me to do that?